# How can I stream data, on my Mac, from a bluetooth source using R?

Tags: python, macos, r, bluetooth

I have a device that is connected to my Mac via bluetooth. I would like to use R (or maybe Python, but R is preferred) to read the data real-time and process it. Does anyone know how I can do the data streaming using R on a Mac?
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a strong probability that you can enumerate the bluetooth as serial port for the bluetooth and use pyserial module to communicate pretty easily...

but if this device does not enumerate serially you will have a very large headache trying to do this...

see if there are any com ports that are available if there are its almost definitely enumerating as a serial connection